# display 2 different arrays in a material ui react card

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get 2 separate arrays to be able to be displayed, preferably on a single card.

Here is my current code attempting to get them on 2 separate cards that will be next to each other, but the second `array.map` will show

> Uncaught TypeError: segmentData.map(...) is not a function

Ideally I would like to combine the info from both arrays on a single card.

```
return (
    (segmentData.map((segment) => (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {segment.flightNumber}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            This CardContent is wrapped in a CardActionsArea, so this text and
            the above header are wrapped in a ButtonBase, which means they
            behave like a Button.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>

    )))

    (pricedItineraryData.map((priced) => (
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              {priced.totalFare}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              This CardContent is wrapped in a CardActionsArea, so this text and
              the above header are wrapped in a ButtonBase, which means they
              behave like a Button.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
      )))
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks like `segmentData` isn't an array at least on the first render. To get them on the same card you'll need to merge the arrays or access the second by index of the first. Also you'll need a containing parent element if you're going to map them in parallel like this.

Comment: Merging did work so I could use the data from both arrays. Thanks for that.